# Passing Query string from jquery datatable to server on row delete

Tags: jquery, query-string, row, datatables

I am using jquery editable Datatable.When ever a table row is deleted,i want to get its row data and build a query string and pass it to the server url.Now i can get the row data but how do i pass query string to the server in ajax request ??

This is the jquery code which i am using.

```
   $(document).ready( function () {
       oTable=$('#example').dataTable({
                                  "bProcessing": true,
                                  "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/questions/Test/listener",
               "fnInitComplete": function (){
                $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).click(function (){
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
            alert(aData[0]);
                });
                        },
                aoColumns: [ { "bVisible": false} , null, null, null, null ]
                                }
                                ).makeEditable({
                                sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
                                            sAddURL: "AddData.php",
                                sAddHttpMethod: "GET", 
                                            sDeleteURL: "http://localhost/questions/Test/DeleteData",
                                sDeleteHttpMethod: "GET", 
                                    });
        } );
```

Comment: Sorry the code's formatting is horrible,i know! Its just that i pasted the code to the word file and pasted it here...:)

Comment: A tip on formatting.  Download an editor like notepad++ and make sure it's formatted correctly in there; you can then you can directly paste it here.  Unreadable code makes it really hard for people to want to help you when you haven't made the effort to make us understand your problem.